# How to add normal text to frontmatter of elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle

I'm using the elsarticle documentclass for my paper. Beneath title and author, number of figures, tables etc. is requested on the titlepage. How can I write extra text in the frontmatter area? For example:

"Number of pages: ; Number of figures: ; Number of tables: 
Number of words in the abstract: ; introduction: ; discussion: 
Total number of words in the text:
Conflict of interest:"

```
\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{annesstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}
\author[firstaddress]{Aaddress}
\author[secondaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress]{Haddress}
\author[thirdaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress,firstaddress]{address}

\address{Address for correspondance:}

\address[firstaddress]{address}
\address[secondaddress]{address}

\begin{abstract}abstract\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}keywords\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Who's requiring the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `preprint` style, here's a patch:

```
\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% patch `\maketitle` to accommodate the new information, printed after the keywords
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
  {\fi\hrule}% the second rule
  {\fi\ifvoid\extrainfobox\else\unvbox\extrainfobox\par\vskip10pt\fi\hrule}
  {}{}

% an environment for the new information
\newenvironment{extrainfo}
  {\global\setbox\extrainfobox=\vbox\bgroup\parindent=0pt }
  {\egroup}
\newsavebox\extrainfobox

\bibliographystyle{annesstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}
\author[firstaddress]{Aaddress}
\author[secondaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress]{Haddress}
\author[thirdaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress,firstaddress]{address}

\address{Address for correspondance:}

\address[firstaddress]{address}
\address[secondaddress]{address}

\begin{abstract}abstract\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}keywords\end{keyword}

\begin{extrainfo}
Number of pages: ;\\
Number of figures: ;\\
Number of tables: ;\\
Number of words in the abstract: ;\\
Introduction: ;\\
discussion: ;\\
Total number of words in the text: ;\\
Conflict of interest:
\end{extrainfo}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the way to have the extra information before the abstract:

```
\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
  {\hrule\vskip12pt}% the second rule
  {\hrule\vskip12pt\ifvoid\extrainfobox\else\unvbox\extrainfobox\par\vskip12pt\fi}
  {}{}

\newenvironment{extrainfo}
  {\global\setbox\extrainfobox=\vbox\bgroup\parindent=0pt }
  {\egroup}
\newsavebox\extrainfobox

\bibliographystyle{annesstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}
\author[firstaddress]{Aaddress}
\author[secondaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress]{Haddress}
\author[thirdaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress]{address}
\author[thirdaddress,firstaddress]{address}

\address{Address for correspondance:}

\address[firstaddress]{address}
\address[secondaddress]{address}

\begin{abstract}abstract\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}keywords\end{keyword}

\begin{extrainfo}
Number of pages: ;\\
Number of figures: ;\\
Number of tables: ;\\
Number of words in the abstract: ;\\
Introduction: ;\\
discussion: ;\\
Total number of words in the text: ;\\
Conflict of interest:
\end{extrainfo}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The text in the second arguments of `\patchcmd` is the code that we want to replace in the definition of `\pprintMaketitle` with the code contained in the third argument. It's easier than copying the entire definition and modifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the patch, it works well. But what do I have to do, to get the abstract after the extrainformation? And what do the lines  {\fi\hrule}% the second rule
  {\fi\ifvoid\extrainfobox\else\unvbox\extrainfobox\par\vskip10pt\fi\hrule} d0?

Comment: @Anne I have added the alternative version

Comment: doesn't work for me! apears before the abstract instead of after it.

Comment: @Hamid Difficult to say. Please, open a new question with details about your issue.